# Azure Search Service filter search.ismatch() not returning correct result when search contains special characters

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am using search.ismatch() in filter of Azure Search Service, when my search terms contains special characters like [-,&,;] it is not giving proper results. Following are the details

function called is search.ismatch('knet-q&a','fieldName','full','all')
here I am using standard lucene analyzer and when results are returned it is returning results which has knet in addition to other words, I expected that it should return result which contains all three terms (knet, q, a). It seems as soon as it sees a special character azure ignores rest of the letters and just return results having knet term.

Few question

1. Is this the correct behavior above or a bug in the way azure returns result
2. If I use a customer analyzer or keyword analyzer will filter consider that while query processing or is it like analyzer will not be considered because it is a filter and not a search term
3. If analyzers would be considered during query processing is it better to use a keyword analyzers which will preserve all special characters while indexing and during search I can pass a regex to match special chars

Thanks In Advance

Thanks
Pratik

Answer (score 0):

1-As far as I know it's correct. The default analyzer removes special chars.

2-You can create a custom analyzer or work with one that don't remove special chars, you'll just need to reindex the content.

3-analyzers will work at the index time.